# separate line output by groups

Tags: python

My python script checks `mysqldump` and if any problems script prints :

- Dump is old for db;
- Dump is not complete for db;
- Dump is empty for db;
- MySQL dump does not exist for db;

Script logs these records to the file line by line.

My question is there are a way to format output in the file like:

```
Dump is old for db;
Dump is old for db;
Dump is old for db;

Dump is not complete for db;
Dump is not complete for db;
Dump is not complete for db;

Dump is empty for db;
Dump is empty for db;
Dump is empty for db;
```

Because now my file looks like:

```
Dump is old for db;
Dump is empty for db;
Dump is old for db;
MySQL dump does not exist for db;
...
etc
```

Here my small script :)

```
#!/bin/env python

import psycopg2
import sys,os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib

con = None
today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

log_dump_fail = '/tmp/mysqldump_FAIL'
log_fail = open(log_dump_fail,'w').close()
log_fail = open(log_dump_fail, 'a')

sender = 'PUT_SENDER_NAME_HERE'
receiver = ['receiver_name']
smtp_daemon_host = 'localhost'

def db_backup_file_does_not_exist(db_backup_file):
    if not os.path.exists(db_backup_file): return True
    else: return False

def dump_health(last_dump_row, file_name,db):
       last_row = last_dump_row.rsplit(" ")
       tms = ''.join(last_row[4:5])
       status = last_row[1:3]

       if (status) and (tms != today):
      log_fail.write("\nDB is old for "+ str(db) + str(file_name) + ", \nDump finished at " + str(''.join(tms)))
      log_fail.write("\n-------------------------------------------")
       elif not (status) and (tms == None):
      log_fail.write("\nDump is not complete for "+str(db) +  str(file_name) + " , end of file is not correct") 
      log_fail.write("\n-------------------------------------------")

suffixes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB']
def humansize(nbytes):
    if nbytes == 0: return '0 B'
    i = 0
    while nbytes >= 1024 and i < len(suffixes)-1:
        nbytes /= 1024.
        i += 1
    f = ('%.2f' % nbytes).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    return '%s %s' % (f, suffixes[i])

def dump_size(dump_file, file_name,db):
       size = os.path.getsize(dump_file)
       if (size < 1024):
      human_readable = humansize(size)
          log_fail.write("\nDump is empty for " +str(db) + "\n" +"\t" + str (file_name)+", file size is " + str(human_readable))
      log_fail.write("\n-------------------------------------------")

def report_to_noc(isubject,text):
    TEXT = text
        SUBJECT = subject
        message = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (SUBJECT, TEXT)
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_daemon_host)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
        server.quit()

try:    
    con = psycopg2.connect(database='**', user='***', password='***', host='****') 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""\
select ad.servicename, (select name from servers where id = ps.server_id) as servername 
from packages as p, account_data as ad, package_servers as ps 
where p.id=ad.package_id and 
p.date_deleted IS NULL and 
p.id=ps.package_id and 
p.aktuel IS NULL and 
p.pre_def_package_id = 4 and  
p.mother_package_id !=0 and 
ps.subservice_id=5 and  
p.mother_package_id NOT IN (select id from packages where date_deleted IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY servername; 
""")

    while (1):
        row = cur.fetchone ()
        if row == None:
            break

    db = row[0]
        server_name = str(row[1])
    if (''.join(server_name) == 'SKIP_THIS') or (''.join(server_name) == 'SKIP_THIS'):
        continue
    else:
        db_backup_file = '/storage/backup/db/mysql/' + str(db) + '/current/' + str(db) + '.mysql.gz'
        db_backup_file2 = '/storage/backup/' + str(''.join(server_name.split("DB"))) + '/mysql/' + str(db) + '/current/'+ str(db) + '.mysql.gz'

    db_file_does_not_exist = False
    db_file2_does_not_exist = False

    if db_backup_file_does_not_exist(db_backup_file):
        db_file_does_not_exist = True   
    if db_backup_file_does_not_exist(db_backup_file2):
        db_file2_does_not_exist = True

        if db_file_does_not_exist and db_file2_does_not_exist:
                log_fail.write("\nMySQL dump does not exist for " + str(db) +  "\n" + "\t" + str(db_backup_file2) + "\n" + "\t" +  str(db_backup_file))
        log_fail.write("\n-------------------------------------------")
        continue
    elif (db_file_does_not_exist) and not (db_file2_does_not_exist):
        p_zcat = Popen(["zcat", db_backup_file2], stdout=PIPE)
                p_tail = Popen(["tail", "-2"], stdin=p_zcat.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
                dump_status =  str(p_tail.communicate()[0])
                dump_health(dump_status,db_backup_file2,db)
                dump_size(db_backup_file2, db_backup_file2,db)
        elif (db_file2_does_not_exist) and not (db_file_does_not_exist):
        p_zcat = Popen(["zcat", db_backup_file], stdout=PIPE)
                p_tail = Popen(["tail", "-2"], stdin=p_zcat.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
                dump_status =  str(p_tail.communicate()[0])
                dump_health(dump_status,db_backup_file,db) 
        dump_size(db_backup_file,db_backup_file,db)       

    con.close()

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e    
    sys.exit(1)

log_fail.close()

if os.path.getsize(log_dump_fail) > 0:
        subject = "Not all MySQL dumps completed successfully. Log file backup:" + str(log_dump_fail)
        fh = open(log_dump_fail, 'r')
        text = fh.read()
        fh.close()
        report_to_noc(subject,text)
else:
        subject = "MySQL dump completed successfullyi for all DBs, listed in PC"
        text = "Hello! \nI am notifying you that I checked mysqldump files this morning.\nThere are nothing to worry about. :)"
        report_to_noc(subject,text)
```

Comment: I am sure there are a few ways to do this - but to get an answer that means anything to you, you need to show us the code that you are using.

Comment: Without a description how exactly the formatting should be done, the example is useless. Do you want to group them by type? Or just add a newline when the next type is different? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You can process your log file after it has been written.

One option is to read your file and sort the lines:

```
lines = open('log.txt').readlines()
lines.sort()
open('log_sorted.txt', 'w').write("\n".join(lines))
```

This won't emit an empty line between log types.

Another option is to use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
lines = open('log.txt').readlines()
counter = Counter()
for line in lines:
    counter[line] += 1

out_file = open('log_sorted.txt', 'w')
for line, num in counter.iteritems():
    out_file.write(line * num + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to group the output of the script, rather than log the info as it comes while searching. 
Easiest would be to maintain 4 lists, on each for empty, not empty and so on. In the script add the db names to appropriate list instead of logging, and then dump the lists one by one into the file with appropriate prefixes("not empty for" + dbname).
For example, remove all the log_fail.write() from the functions and replace them with list.append() and write a separate function that writes to the log file as you like:

Add lists:

```
db_dump_is_old_list = []
db_dump_is_empty_list = []
db_dump_is_not_complete_list = []
db_dump_does_not_exist_list = []
```

Modify the Functions:

```
def dump_health(last_dump_row, file_name,db):
   last_row = last_dump_row.rsplit(" ")
   tms = ''.join(last_row[4:5])
   status = last_row[1:3]

   if (status) and (tms != today):
    db_dump_is_old_list.append(str(db))
    #log_fail.write("\nDB is old for "+ str(db) + str(file_name) + ", \nDump finished at " + str(''.join(tms)))
    #log_fail.write("\n-------------------------------------------")
   elif not (status) and (tms == None):
    db_dump_is_not_complete_list.append(str(db)
    #log_fail.write("\nDump is not complete for "+str(db) +  str(file_name) + " , end of file is not correct") 
    #log_fail.write("\n-------------------------------------------")


def dump_size(dump_file, file_name,db):
       size = os.path.getsize(dump_file)
       if (size < 1024):
        human_readable = humansize(size)
        db_dump_is_empty_list.append(str(db))
        #log_fail.write("\nDump is empty for " +str(db) + "\n" +"\t" + str (file_name)+", file size is " + str(human_readable))
        #log_fail.write("\n-------------------------------------------")


if db_file_does_not_exist and db_file2_does_not_exist:
        db_dump_does_not_exist_list.append(str(db))
        #log_fail.write("\nMySQL dump does not exist for " + str(db) +  "\n" + "\t" + str(db_backup_file2) + "\n" + "\t" +  str(db_backup_file))
        #log_fail.write("\n-------------------------------------------")
        continue
```

And add a logger function:

```
def dump_info_to_log_file():
    log_dump_fail = '/tmp/mysqldump_FAIL'
    log_fail = open(log_dump_fail,'w').close()
    log_fail = open(log_dump_fail, 'a')

    for dbname in db_dump_is_old_list:
        log_fail.write("Dump is Old for" + str(dbname))

    log_fail.write("\n\n")

    for dbname in db_dump_is_empty_list:
        log_fail.write("Dump is Empty for" + str(dbname))

    log_fail.write("\n\n")

    for dbname in db_dump_is_not_complete_list:
        log_fail.write("Dump is Not Complete for" + str(dbname))

    log_fail.write("\n\n")

    for dbname in db_dump_does_not_exist_list:
        log_fail.write("Dump Does Not Exist for" + str(dbname))

    log_fail.close()
```

Or you could simply log as you are doing, and then read in the file, sort and write back the file.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it helped you solve your problem :-). It ll help others looking at similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for all interesting ideas.
I have really tried all options :)

To my mind:
With Counter object the pros is to few lines of code.
But cons are - many read\write operations. Log file is not big, however, I decided to decrease read(s) \ write(s)

With array the cons are to many lines of code :) but the pros is - write to the file only once.

So I implemented arrays.. :)

Thank you guys!!!